# Tip: how to get a list of objects in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, documentation

sometimes I have completed the development of a solution on a development instance of a SQL database, after several test cycles, reworks, adjustments, etc.

When is time to move everything in production, I have to be sure that nothing is left behind by mistake (a trigger, a stored procedure).

Answer (score 1):

One helper is to get a simple list of all the objects in the database.

A simple query to get the list of all the objects in your db is the following one:

```
select * from Sys.objects as o left join sys.schemas as s on o.schema_id = s.schema_id
where is_ms_shipped = 0
order by s.name, o.type, o.name
```

You can adjust it at your needs, remove fields, and so on.

Few notes:

1. I have excluded items delivered by Microsoft (is_ms_shipped)
2. I have joined the main system table with a catalogue of all the objects with the description of the schema. This is helpful to order all the elements

Using SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio), you can easily export the results in Excel, and work on it, add it to the documentation.